# Flutter Push Notification onLaunch call infinitely

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm creating a Push Navigation to ChatScreen if there's a Notification.
It is pushing, but the problem is it is pushing infinitely.

I use this for the firebase messaging

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      //Display when the apps on close
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch : $message\n");
        if (message['data']['type'] == 'like') {
          print("Navigate to Notification");
          print("type : ${message['data']['type']}");
        } else if (message['data']['type'] == 'chat') {
          print("userID : ${message['data']['userID']}");
          print("sellerID : ${message['data']['sellerID']}");
          print("type : ${message['data']['type']}");
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ChatScreen(
                userID: message['data']['userID'],
                sellerID: message['data']['sellerID'],
                productName: "",
                firstMessage: "",
                price: 0,
                imageUrls: [""],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      //Display when the apps on background
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume : $message\n");
        if (message['data']['type'] == 'like') {
          print("Navigate to Notification");
          print("type : ${message['data']['type']}");
        } else if (message['data']['type'] == 'chat') {
          print("userID : ${message['data']['userID']}");
          print("sellerID : ${message['data']['sellerID']}");
          print("type : ${message['data']['type']}");
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ChatScreen(
                userID: message['data']['userID'],
                sellerID: message['data']['sellerID'],
                productName: "",
                firstMessage: "",
                price: 0,
                imageUrls: [""],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      //Display when the apps is active
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage : $message\n");

      },
    );
```

this is what happen on the apps
[image]

and this is the output on the Terminal

```
I/flutter (13793): onLaunch : {data: {google.sent_time: 1568110868915, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, userID: IGgqN2pqzKPk6pNN7Sl3NT8mois2, google.original_priority: high, status: done, collapse_key: id.co.sprout.etalase, sellerID: VduOp2mICGcLjQDXFXJVRrkmV6n2, groupChatID: IGgqN2pqzKPk6pNN7Sl3NT8mois2-VduOp2mICGcLjQDXFXJVRrkmV6n2, google.delivered_priority: high, sound: default, from: 11013836573, type: chat, google.message_id: 0:1568110868934877%c5168753c5168753, google.ttl: 2419200}, notification: {}}
I/flutter (13793): userID : IGgqN2pqzKPk6pNN7Sl3NT8mois2
I/flutter (13793): sellerID : VduOp2mICGcLjQDXFXJVRrkmV6n2
I/flutter (13793): type : chat
I/flutter (13793): Token: cOZlHYsGTKk:APA91bFsYC1DBR-Ysij14IwGienYN9Prq5JiBsvVBaVtthKAb0ZCfOxGW4cKU95IQqA3zw-BkunLe8G5wB4FLFvYDPDj_WvRLY377yNU2pX5R0N6C3vMg5xHCSfhmzJtF_16Yp5ovxfg
```

and it is loop Infinitely

Comment: Make sure your firebase code isn't inside the build method because anything inside the build method will get called multiple times e.g whenever there is a layout change.

Comment: the function is already outside the Screen Build

the code is below initState, but it is called on didChangeDependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own problem

I put it on didChangeDependencies so it called again and again

now I put it on initState, and solve the problem